# setting source to web view resulted in invalid cast exception

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to set source to my WebView in my ViewModel, however it resulted in invalid cast exception. I have tried to set the source directly In xml and it worked so I must be doing something wrong in the viewModel. Could you please advise

My ViewModel

```
 public WebViewSource PageSource
            {
                get => (string) GetValue(_pageSource);
                set => SetValue(_pageSource, value);
            }
    
            private readonly BindableProperty _pageSource = BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: nameof(PageSource),
                returnType: typeof(WebViewSource),
                defaultValue: default(WebViewSource),
                declaringType: typeof(WebBrowserViewModel));
```

And then I have this in the constructor

```
 public WebBrowserViewModel()
  {
            WebViewSource source = new UrlWebViewSource
                        {
                            Url = "https://google.com"
                        };
                        PageSource = source;
                
    }
```

my xaml

```
<page:Page.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:WebBrowserViewModel />
    </page:Page.BindingContext>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
            <WebView 
                Source="{Binding PageSource}"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>        
</page:Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the incorrect type in getter method .

Change your  code from

```
 public WebViewSource PageSource
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(_pageSource);
        set => SetValue(_pageSource, value);
    }
```

To

```
 public WebViewSource PageSource
    {
        get => (WebViewSource)GetValue(_pageSource);
        set => SetValue(_pageSource, value);
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't notice, such foolish mistake